# How to convert an integer column as a comma separated row in Azure sql

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Anyone can help please I want to Convert sql table column to a comma 
    separated row 
    in azure sql
    I have already tried this code but getting error that can not convert to 
    varchar please suggest

```
DECLARE @Country TABLE (id INT, [Name] Varchar(30) )

INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (1,'India')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (2,'USA')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (3,'Japan')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (4,'China')
INSERT INTO @Country VALUES (5,'Switzerland')

SELECT STUFF( -- Remove first comma
(SELECT  ', ' + ID FROM -- create comma separated values
(SELECT ID FROM @Country --Your query here
) AS T FOR XML PATH('')
)
,1,1,'') AS [Name]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(ID, ', ') FROM @Country
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f031c59d925317682596c52b58ba01d9)**

XML + STUFF is old way when there was no GROUP_CONCAT equivalent available.

Answer (score 1):

You need CAST the integer

```
SELECT  ', ' + CAST(ID as nvarchar(max)) FROM
```